# Problems setting fail2ban apache rules

Tags: apache-2.2, fail2ban, ubuntu-16.04

Im using ubunutu 16.04. I install fail2ban and everything works wells. I try an ssh false login attempt, and it bans my ip as it should do. So well everything is nice at this point. But i need to implement some apache rules, so i proceed to edit jail.local.
I search the rules that i whish to enable, and change them to enabled = true . I finish, save. Reboot  (`sudo service fail2ban restart`). And i proceed to check:

```
sudo fail2ban-client status
```

But i receive: Unable to contact server. Is it running?

I check the rules with

```
sudo iptables -S
```

And i receive:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

Notice theres nothing, even the SSH rule which is working when I do a fresh install disappears. I dont know what else can I do

Ive followed the following tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-apache-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04

Fail2ban LOG

```
 2017-02-17 14:10:38,917 fail2ban.server [31044]: INFO    Stopping all jails
2017-02-17 14:10:39,197 fail2ban.actions[31044]: WARNING [ssh] Unban 116.31.116.52
2017-02-17 14:10:39,204 fail2ban.actions[31044]: WARNING [ssh] Unban 80.242.71.53
2017-02-17 14:10:39,211 fail2ban.jail   [31044]: INFO    Jail 'ssh' stopped
2017-02-17 14:10:39,212 fail2ban.server [31044]: INFO    Exiting Fail2ban
```

syslog

```
 Feb 17 14:10:38 vps374063 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start/stop fail2ban...
Feb 17 14:10:39 vps374063 fail2ban[31145]: Stopping authentication failure monitor: fail2ban.
Feb 17 14:10:39 vps374063 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop fail2ban...
Feb 17 14:10:39 vps374063 fail2ban[31168]: Starting authentication failure monitor: fail2banERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/apache/error.log
Feb 17 14:10:39 vps374063 fail2ban[31168]: ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for apache-noscript jail
Feb 17 14:10:39 vps374063 fail2ban[31168]: failed!
Feb 17 14:10:39 vps374063 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/stop fail2ban.
```

jail.conf

```
    # Fail2Ban configuration file.
#
# This file was composed for Debian systems from the original one
# provided now under /usr/share/doc/fail2ban/examples/jail.conf
# for additional examples.
#
# Comments: use '#' for comment lines and ';' for inline comments
#
# To avoid merges during upgrades DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE
# and rather provide your changes in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
#

# The DEFAULT allows a global definition of the options. They can be overridden
# in each jail afterwards.

[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be
# defined using space separator.
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8

# External command that will take an tagged arguments to ignore, e.g. <ip>,
# and return true if the IP is to be ignored. False otherwise.
#
# ignorecommand = /path/to/command <ip>
ignorecommand =

# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime  = 600

# A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime"
# seconds.
findtime = 600
maxretry = 3

# "backend" specifies the backend used to get files modification.
# Available options are "pyinotify", "gamin", "polling" and "auto".
# This option can be overridden in each jail as well.
#
# pyinotify: requires pyinotify (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#            If pyinotify is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# gamin:     requires Gamin (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#            If Gamin is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# polling:   uses a polling algorithm which does not require external libraries.
# auto:      will try to use the following backends, in order:
#            pyinotify, gamin, polling.
backend = auto

# "usedns" specifies if jails should trust hostnames in logs,
#   warn when reverse DNS lookups are performed, or ignore all hostnames in logs
#
# yes:   if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed.
# warn:  if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed,
#        but it will be logged as a warning.
# no:    if a hostname is encountered, will not be used for banning,
#        but it will be logged as info.
usedns = warn

#
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in
# jail.{conf,local} configuration files.
destemail = root@localhost

#
# Name of the sender for mta actions
sendername = Fail2Ban

# Email address of the sender
sender = fail2ban@localhost

#
# ACTIONS
#

# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define
# action_* variables. Can be overridden globally or per
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-multiport

# email action. Since 0.8.1 upstream fail2ban uses sendmail
# MTA for the mailing. Change mta configuration parameter to mail
# if you want to revert to conventional 'mail'.
mta = sendmail

# Default protocol
protocol = tcp

# Specify chain where jumps would need to be added in iptables-* actions
chain = INPUT

#
# Action shortcuts. To be used to define action parameter

# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
# to the destemail.
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section
action = %(action_)s

#
# JAILS
#

# Next jails corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban 0.6 which
# was shipped in Debian. Enable any defined here jail by including
#
# [SECTION_NAME]
# enabled = true

#
# in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.
#
# Optionally you may override any other parameter (e.g. banaction,
# action, port, logpath, etc) in that section within jail.local

[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 5

[dropbear]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = dropbear
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

# Generic filter for pam. Has to be used with action which bans all ports
# such as iptables-allports, shorewall
[pam-generic]

enabled  = false
# pam-generic filter can be customized to monitor specific subset of 'tty's
filter   = pam-generic
# port actually must be irrelevant but lets leave it all for some possible uses
port     = all
banaction = iptables-allports
port     = anyport
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[xinetd-fail]

enabled   = false
filter    = xinetd-fail
port      = all
banaction = iptables-multiport-log
logpath   = /var/log/daemon.log
maxretry  = 2


[ssh-ddos]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd-ddos
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6


# Here we use blackhole routes for not requiring any additional kernel support
# to store large volumes of banned IPs

[ssh-route]

enabled = false
filter = sshd
action = route
logpath = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry = 6

# Here we use a combination of Netfilter/Iptables and IPsets
# for storing large volumes of banned IPs
#
# IPset comes in two versions. See ipset -V for which one to use
# requires the ipset package and kernel support.
[ssh-iptables-ipset4]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto4
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry = 6

[ssh-iptables-ipset6]

enabled  = false
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry = 6


#
# HTTP servers
#

[apache]

enabled  = false
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-auth
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 6

# default action is now multiport, so apache-multiport jail was left
# for compatibility with previous (<0.7.6-2) releases
[apache-multiport]

enabled   = false
port      = http,https
filter    = apache-auth
logpath   = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry  = 6

[apache-noscript]

enabled  = false
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 6

[apache-overflows]

enabled  = false
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-overflows
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2

[apache-modsecurity]

enabled  = false
filter   = apache-modsecurity
port     = http,https
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2

[apache-nohome]

enabled  = false
filter   = apache-nohome
port     = http,https
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2

# Ban attackers that try to use PHP's URL-fopen() functionality
# through GET/POST variables. - Experimental, with more than a year
# of usage in production environments.

[php-url-fopen]

enabled = false
port    = http,https
filter  = php-url-fopen
logpath = /var/www/*/logs/access_log

# A simple PHP-fastcgi jail which works with lighttpd.
# If you run a lighttpd server, then you probably will
# find these kinds of messages in your error_log:
#   ALERT – tried to register forbidden variable ‘GLOBALS’
#   through GET variables (attacker '1.2.3.4', file '/var/www/default/htdocs/index.php')

[lighttpd-fastcgi]

enabled = false
port    = http,https
filter  = lighttpd-fastcgi
logpath = /var/log/lighttpd/error.log

# Same as above for mod_auth
# It catches wrong authentifications

[lighttpd-auth]

enabled = false
port    = http,https
filter  = suhosin
logpath = /var/log/lighttpd/error.log

[nginx-http-auth]

enabled = false
filter  = nginx-http-auth
port    = http,https
logpath = /var/log/nginx/error.log

# Monitor roundcube server

[roundcube-auth]

enabled  = false
filter   = roundcube-auth
port     = http,https
logpath  = /var/log/roundcube/userlogins


[sogo-auth]

enabled  = false
filter   = sogo-auth
port     = http, https
# without proxy this would be:
# port    = 20000
logpath  = /var/log/sogo/sogo.log


#
# FTP servers
#

[vsftpd]

enabled  = false
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data
filter   = vsftpd
logpath  = /var/log/vsftpd.log
# or overwrite it in jails.local to be
# logpath = /var/log/auth.log
# if you want to rely on PAM failed login attempts
# vsftpd's failregex should match both of those formats
maxretry = 6


[proftpd]

enabled  = false
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data
filter   = proftpd
logpath  = /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
maxretry = 6


[pure-ftpd]

enabled  = false
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data
filter   = pure-ftpd
logpath  = /var/log/syslog
maxretry = 6


[wuftpd]

enabled  = false
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data
filter   = wuftpd
logpath  = /var/log/syslog
maxretry = 6


#
# Mail servers
#

[postfix]

enabled  = false
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission
filter   = postfix
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log


[couriersmtp]

enabled  = false
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission
filter   = couriersmtp
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log


#
# Mail servers authenticators: might be used for smtp,ftp,imap servers, so
# all relevant ports get banned
#

[courierauth]

enabled  = false
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s
filter   = courierlogin
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log


[sasl]

enabled  = false
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s
filter   = postfix-sasl
# You might consider monitoring /var/log/mail.warn instead if you are
# running postfix since it would provide the same log lines at the
# "warn" level but overall at the smaller filesize.
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log

[dovecot]

enabled = false
port    = smtp,ssmtp,submission,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s
filter  = dovecot
logpath = /var/log/mail.log

# To log wrong MySQL access attempts add to /etc/my.cnf:
# log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
# log-warning = 2
[mysqld-auth]

enabled  = false
filter   = mysqld-auth
port     = 3306
logpath  = /var/log/mysqld.log


# DNS Servers


# These jails block attacks against named (bind9). By default, logging is off
# with bind9 installation. You will need something like this:
#
# logging {
#     channel security_file {
#         file "/var/log/named/security.log" versions 3 size 30m;
#         severity dynamic;
#         print-time yes;
#     };
#     category security {
#         security_file;
#     };
# };
#
# in your named.conf to provide proper logging

# !!! WARNING !!!
#   Since UDP is connection-less protocol, spoofing of IP and imitation
#   of illegal actions is way too simple.  Thus enabling of this filter
#   might provide an easy way for implementing a DoS against a chosen
#   victim. See
#    http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/690-fail2ban-+-dns-fail.html
#   Please DO NOT USE this jail unless you know what you are doing.
#[named-refused-udp]
#
#enabled  = false
#port     = domain,953
#protocol = udp
#filter   = named-refused
#logpath  = /var/log/named/security.log

[named-refused-tcp]

enabled  = false
port     = domain,953
protocol = tcp
filter   = named-refused
logpath  = /var/log/named/security.log

[freeswitch]

enabled  = false
filter   = freeswitch
logpath  = /var/log/freeswitch.log
maxretry = 10
action   = iptables-multiport[name=freeswitch-tcp, port="5060,5061,5080,5081", protocol=tcp]
           iptables-multiport[name=freeswitch-udp, port="5060,5061,5080,5081", protocol=udp]

[ejabberd-auth]

enabled  = false
filter   = ejabberd-auth
port     = xmpp-client
protocol = tcp
logpath  = /var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log


# Multiple jails, 1 per protocol, are necessary ATM:
# see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/37
[asterisk-tcp]

enabled  = false
filter   = asterisk
port     = 5060,5061
protocol = tcp
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages

[asterisk-udp]

enabled  = false
filter   = asterisk
port     = 5060,5061
protocol = udp
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages


# Jail for more extended banning of persistent abusers
# !!! WARNING !!!
#   Make sure that your loglevel specified in fail2ban.conf/.local
#   is not at DEBUG level -- which might then cause fail2ban to fall into
#   an infinite loop constantly feeding itself with non-informative lines
[recidive]

enabled  = false
filter   = recidive
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
action   = iptables-allports[name=recidive]
           sendmail-whois-lines[name=recidive, logpath=/var/log/fail2ban.log]
bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week
findtime = 86400   ; 1 day
maxretry = 5

# See the IMPORTANT note in action.d/blocklist_de.conf for when to
# use this action
#
# Report block via blocklist.de fail2ban reporting service API
# See action.d/blocklist_de.conf for more information
[ssh-blocklist]

enabled  = false
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=SSH, dest="%(destemail)s", sender="%(sender)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
           blocklist_de[email="%(sender)s", apikey="xxxxxx", service="%(filter)s"]
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry = 20


# consider low maxretry and a long bantime
# nobody except your own Nagios server should ever probe nrpe
[nagios]
enabled  = false
filter   = nagios
action   = iptables[name=Nagios, port=5666, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=Nagios, dest="%(destemail)s", sender="%(sender)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
logpath  = /var/log/messages     ; nrpe.cfg may define a different log_facility
maxretry = 1
```

Comment: What does syslog say? and failban.log?

Comment: @Orphans Ive added the log

Comment: Can you post the jail config as well?  Looks like it can't find the Apache log.

Comment: The apache-noscript jail is configured parsing a non-existing file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is there:

```
ERROR  No file(s) found for glob /var/log/apache/error.log
ERROR  Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for apache-noscript jail
```

Give an other look to your jails configuration, the error log you're parsing with the `apache-noscript` jail may not exist.

---

Your edit shows:

```
[apache-noscript]
enabled  = false
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 6
```

My bet is that from a console, `ls /var/log/apache*/*error.log` would not match anything.

Comment: it had to bee apache2*/*error.log . Finally solved

Comment: @romanturbo You should change the title ;) It's not impossible :P

Comment: @romanturbo, `/var/log/apache*/*error.log` will definitely match `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. I have the same settings and I can confirm you. I guess you had a typo in jail.conf and it was `/var/log/apache/*error.log` which will not match.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is an accepted answer, but there is something to add:

The default apache-noscript block in jail.conf is correct and should work perfectly.

It's because,  `/var/log/apache*/*error.log` will definitely match `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. And there is no need to change it to `/var/log/apache2*/*error.log`.

The default apache2 error log location for Ubuntu 16.04 is `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and so it should just work with  fail2ban.

The error can only mean that, there was a typo in jail.conf as something like `/var/log/apache/*error.log` and could not find anything matching.